# Callback to Lua member function

Tags: lua, luabind

I have a lua "animation variable" which has a callback function used in an animation loop.

```
local av = AnimationVariable(ticker.Position.Y)
...
av:addCallback( ** animation function goes here **)
```

Skipping over details, this addCallback function is defined as follows in C++:

```
void LuaUIAnimationVariable::addCallback(luabind::object callback);
```

and when the animation variable is updated, the callback is executed as such (we call the function with one argument):

```
luabind::call_function<void>(boost::ref(callback), newValue);
```

My question is the following: **How can I use a member function with addCallback?** Assuming I have a `Ticker:animate(ypos)` function, using addCallback on a Ticker instance `addCallBack(ticker:animate)` does not compile, and `addCallBack(ticker.animate)` does not work. I understand that member functions in lua have an implicit "self" first parameter.

Any solution or am I forced to use a global function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question, but if you mean a Lua member function, you can use a closure:

```
av:addCallback(function(yval) ticker:animate(yval) end)
```

Comment: This assumes that ticker is global, doesn't it? Problem is addCallback is inside a for-loop which goes through all my tickers.

Comment: It only assumes that `ticker` is within scope; whatever `ticker` refers to at the time the closure is created is what it will refer to whenever you call it.

Comment: @num3ric that's why they call it a closure. It captures the variable at the time it's created and remains unaffected if you assign to the variable outside the closure.

Comment: @furq: "whatever ticker refers to at the time the closure is created is what it will refer to whenever you call it." That's *only* true if it is a local variable. If `ticker` is global, then it will attempt to access the global variable every time the function is called. Lua closures only close over local variables.